# deploy NPM files to the artifactory offline

Tags: windows, npm, repository, artifactory, npm-debug

I am trying to deploy an Tgz file to the artifactory server in windows offline

the problem is the dependencies of the npm files so I want someway that I don't have to delete the npm from the artifactory to deploy new npm …

again I am working offline and I want to deploy an new npm files with the dependencies
I am working with windows 10/windows 7. 
thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to delete in order to deploy a new version?

Comment: What is the problem? What did you try? How it didn't work/failed/broke?